# October CMS, I can't make Subscribe form by Magic forms plug-in

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I have a October CMS setup and I have a Subscribe form in footer.

Footer is a `default.htm`' partial into `Layouts`.

I override **Generic Ajax Form** html with a partial, it's path `partials\subscribe\default.htm` and I include it into `Footer`.

And I try to create **Generic Ajax Form** into `Layouts\default.htm` and `Footer` (`site\footer.htm`) but Ajax handler is not found.

It gave me this message:

```
AJAX handler 'subscribe::onSubscribeSubmit' was not found.
```

### My site tree:

#### `Layouts\default.htm` (I've tried here to setup Magic Forms but it not handle)

```
...
...
{% partial 'site/footer' %}
...
```

#### `site\footer.htm` (I've tried here to setup Magic Forms but it not handle)

```
...
...
{% component "subscribe" %}
...
```

#### `partials\subscribe\default.htm`

```html
<div class="footer-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col text-md-left">
        <div class="fs-24px fw-600 text-white mb-16">
          Sign up for our newsletter
        </div>
        <form class="subscribe-form w-100 mw-500px" data-request="{{ __SELF__ }}::onSubscribeSubmit">
            {{ form_token() }}
            <div id="{{ __SELF__ }}_forms_flash"></div>
          <div class="form-group d-flex">
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control rounded-left font-roboto" placeholder="Enter email address">
            <button type="submit" class="form-control submit font-roboto fs-16px fw-700">
              <span>Sign Up</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should be using `{{ __SELF__ }}::onFormSubmit` handler instead of `{{ __SELF__ }}::onSubscribeSubmit`.

from the plugin's perspective, there is no such event handler `onSubscribeSubmit`.

You can use `{{ __SELF__ }}::onFormSubmit` handler for `Generic Ajax Form`.

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: Actually, it was as you said at first. But I had installed it inside `site\footer.htm` . When I got an error, I thought it conflicted with the existing contact form on the site, so I changed the name. But one thing I skipped trying is when I installed it to `site\default.htm` I tested it with `onSubscribeSubmit` and it misled me. Now, as you say, I tested it and the answer is: In such a case, the `default.htm` file of the site can handle all the pages, (provided, of course, that it has `::onFormSubmit` as you said). Thanks.